# Using Core Data in an asynchronous operation

Tags: multithreading, core-data, nsoperation

I have an iOS sync process broken down into a series of asynchronous NSOperation subclasses. These are broken down into those that do heavy processing and those that rely on networking. But most of them also do things with Core Data.

I'm not sure how to perform Core Data operations within the operation.

Here's a couple trivial examples… my real code does several switches in and out of the database context. It also uses `@synchronize(self){}`.

```
NSManagedContext *context = [self newContextFromParent];
__block NSString *someValue;
[context performBlockAndWait:^{
    // fetch someValue from Core Data
}];
[self doMoreWorkWithValue:someValue];
[context performBlockAndWait:^{
    NSError *e;
    if ([context hasChanges]) {
        [context saveChanges:&e];
    }
}];
```

This seems on the surface like a good approach, but depending on what I do in `performBlockAndWait:` there are potential deadlocks here.

Generally, I like to avoid `performBlockAndWait:` in my code and use `performBlock:` instead.

```
[context performBlock:^{
    NSString *someValue = @""; // fetch someValue from Core Data
    [backgroundQueue addOperationWithBlock:^{
        [self doMoreWorkWithValue:someValue withCompletion:^{
            [context performBlock:^{
                NSError *e;
                if ([context hasChanges]) {
                    [context saveChanges:&e];
                }
            }];
        }];
    }];
}];
```

With this approach, though, I've moved my processing from the thread I was given to whatever thread `backgroundQueue` decides to run my process on, and I'm not sure what the better approach is.

If I capture `[NSOperation currentQueue]` in the main operation and add to it instead, I've added my block to the end of the queue. What I really want is to resume.

What approach should I be using here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first approach is the one I would use. You mentioned concern about deadlocks inside `performBlockAndWait:`, though. Are you concerned about calling into another method that might itself use `performBlockAndWait:`? If so, no worries; `performBlockAndWait:` is explicitly safe to use re-entrantly. That is: this code is safe (though obviously contrived):

```m
[context performBlockAndWait:^{
    [context performBlockAndWait:^{
        // fetch someValue from Core Data
    }];
}];
```

If the deadlock concern is not related to Core Data, then it seems like you'd be at just as much of a risk of deadlock inside `doMoreWorkWithValue:`, right?

Comment: Yes. After I read your reply, I'm thinking the real answer is to be more careful with my `@synchronized{}` blocks and treat them as the real problem. `performBlockAndWait:` and `@synchronized{}` are both reasonable on their own, but as soon as they're nested I'm playing with fire. Is that right?

Comment: The main concern I can see is that `performBlockAndWait:` _might_ run on a different thread (or might not), and `@synchronized` is a thread-based locking mechanism. In general, I try to avoid calling into other methods on `self` from within an `@synchronized` block; it should protect a very small region.

Comment: It should be fine to use `@synchronized{}` from within `performBlockAndWait:`; just don't do it the other way around. Don't call `performBlockAndWait:` from within an `@synchronized{}` block.

Comment: In the current universe I avoid `@synchronized` completely.  There is no need to use it with Core Data at all.  Doing the work in your `performBlockAndWait` will handle any methods you call out of it and when I develop like this my `performBlockAndWait` is usually just a list of calls to methods like a punch list of the work that is actually being done.

Comment: Thereby making the `performBlockAndWait:` blocks as short as possible. Makes sense. Thanks. :)